# Using Antiderivative to compute complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have been practicing solving complex integrals. When am I allowed to simply use the antiderivative of the integral to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve the integral? Is it when it is easy to find the antiderivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [a, b] \to \Bbb{C}$ be continuously differentiable. The path-integral of a complex-valued function $f: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ over the path $\gamma$ is defined to be
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz := \int_a^b f( \gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \,dt\,.
\end{align}
Note that on the right we have a regular Riemann integral. The integrated function can be written in the form
$$
f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) = u(t) + i v(t)\,.
$$
Now 
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = \int_a^b u(t) \, dt + i \int_a^b v(t) \, dt\,.
$$
The integrals $\int_a^b u(t) \, dt$ and $\int_a^b v(t) \, dt$ are regular real Riemann integrals, so you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to them whenever you can find the antiderivative. So assume we have functions $V$, $U$ s.t. $V'(t) = v(t)$ and $U'(t) = u(t)$ for all $t$. Now
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = U(b) - U(a) + i \big( V(b) - V(a) \big)\,.
$$
But in practice, we often don't bother to write $f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ as $u(t) + i v(t)$. We may use shortcuts like the fact that $\frac{d}{dt} e^{it} = i e^{it}$: consider the example $f(z) = 1$ and $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. Now
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} 1 \cdot i e^{it} \, dt \,.
$$
Now we could write $i e^{it}$ as $i( \cos t + i \sin t) = - \sin t + i \cos t$ and find the antiderivatives of the imaginary and real parts, but it's more convenient to use the "complex antiderivative" $e^{it}$. So we have
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = e^{i 2 \pi} - e^{i \cdot 0}\,.
$$

So you are pretty much always using the fundamental theorem of calculus, unless you work with Riemann sums, which I doubt you do too often. Just remember that the path integral is defined as a certain "regular" Riemann integral over an interval. Sometimes the integrated function is complex valued though, but it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: That was very detailed and explained everything perfectly. Thank you.